# How to install PyAutoGUI on Fedora 27

Tags: python, pyautogui, fedora-27

When I run

```
sudo pip3 install PyAutoGUI
```

I receive the following error

```
[root@localhost Projects]# sudo pip install pyautogui 
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip install --user` instead.
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.36.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ywXbn7/pyautogui/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
      File "pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
        from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
      File "pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 7, in <module>
        from Xlib.display import Display
    ImportError: No module named Xlib.display

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ywXbn7/pyautogui/
```

I have followed other troubleshooting advice by installing Pillow and Display and using just the pip command.

I have also attempted installation of PyAutoGUI by cloning the package from GitHub and installing that way, however the following error message is returned:

```
[root@localhost Projects]# git clone https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui
Cloning into 'pyautogui'...
remote: Counting objects: 1079, done.
remote: Total 1079 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1079
Receiving objects: 100% (1079/1079), 2.03 MiB | 697.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (733/733), done.
[root@localhost Projects]# cd pyautogui
[root@localhost pyautogui]# sudo python3 setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    version=__import__('pyautogui').__version__,
  File "/home/luke/Projects/pyautogui/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 115, in <module>
    from . import _pyautogui_x11 as platformModule
  File "/home/luke/Projects/pyautogui/pyautogui/_pyautogui_x11.py", line 160, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":0": b'No protocol specified\n'
```

I am following the instructions from Chapter 18 of Automate the Boring Stuff with the commands slightly altered to suit Fedora 27 Workstation.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is tested on Fedora 30.

First install dependencies

```
sudo dnf install scrot
sudo dnf install python3-tkinter
sudo dnf install python3-devel.x86_64
```

Then install PyAutoGUI with pip (without sudo/root)

```
pip3 install --user python3-xlib
pip3 install --user pyautogui
```

Note:
PyAutoGUI seems to require X, which is not default in Ferodra 30, but can be chosen at the login screen. Look for Xorg.

(Side note: When installing software, it is recommended to use sudo, if you are logged on as root, there is no need for sudo)